# I want to monitor new and changed contacts in Outlook add-in

Tags: c++, com, outlook-addin

I've created an Outlook addin in C++ (VS6!) that monitors the InspectorsCollection to catch when a user opens or closes a contact item. Works great.

Now I want it to track when a user saves a new contact, or modifies an existing one. I figured I'd modify the CInspectorsCollectionEventHandler class to work with contact items. Everything seems to be ok, and FindConnectionPoint() and Advise() succeed, but my Invoke() never gets called.

Here's how I set up, when my dll starts up:

```
Outlook::MAPIFolderPtr pFolder = g_pNameSpace->GetDefaultFolder(Outlook::olFolderContacts);
if (pFolder != NULL) {
    Outlook::_ItemsPtr pContactItems = pFolder->GetItems();
    if (pContactItems != NULL)
        m_pContactItemsEventHandler = new CItemsEventHandler(pContactItems);
}
```

My CItemsEventHandler constructor calls SinkEvents() (below), which executes correctly.

Here are the key parts of my CItemsEventHandler class:

```
STDMETHODIMP CItemsEventHandler::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv)
{
    if (NULL == ppv) return E_POINTER;
    *ppv = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    if ((__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents) == riid) ||
        (IID_IUnknown == riid) || (IID_IDispatch == riid))
        *ppv = static_cast<IDispatch*>(this);
    else
        hr = E_NOINTERFACE;

    if (NULL != *ppv)
        reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(*ppv)->AddRef();

    return hr;
}

void CItemsEventHandler::SinkEvents(LPDISPATCH pItems)
{
    HRESULT hr;

 // Get server's IConnectionPointContainer interface.
    IConnectionPointContainer* pCPC;
    hr = pItems->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void **)&pCPC);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

    // Find connection point for events we're interested in.
        hr = pCPC->FindConnectionPoint(__uuidof(Outlook::ItemsEvents), &m_pConnection);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            AddRef();
            hr = m_pConnection->Advise(static_cast<IDispatch*>(this), &m_dwCookie);
        }
    // Release the IConnectionPointContainer
        pCPC->Release();
    }
}
```

It looks like everything is executing fine, and the code is based on code that works (for Inspectors), but I just don't get any calls to my Invoke()! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Hope this is useful to someone. Turns out that as soon as my pContactItems pointer went out of scope (right after it was used), no events were registered. I moved pContactItems to a global variable and it started working.